# How to find and merge mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, nosql

I'm trying test application that should merge two documents with same key. I thought that findAndModify() will do a job, but it doesn't. For example, lets assume that there is a document in 'data' collection:
{ "Date":"2014-08-23", "field1":"A"}

I tried:

```
bo.put( "Date", "2014-08-23");
bo.put( "field2", "B" );
query.put( "Date", "2014-08-23" );

DBObject resObj = collection.findAndModify( query, bo );
```

The result is { "Date" : "2014-08-23", "field2" : "B" }
And I want { "Date" : "2014-08-23", "field1":"A", "field2" : "B" }

How I can do it within one DB or Collection command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the normal `update` function (or its cousin `findAndModify`) completely replaces a document. When you want to retain the old content and only update some of its fields, you need to use the [`$set` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set).

In MongoDB shell syntax:

```
db.collection.update(
     { "Date": "2014-08-23" },
     { "$set": { "field2": "B"} }
 );
```

In Java syntax:

```
DBObject where = new BasicDBObject("Date", "2014-08-23");
DBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("field2", "B"));
collection.update(where, update);
```

Comment: It is working for me with small change:
DBObject resObj = collection.findOne( query );  
if ( resObj == null )
   collection.insert( bo );  
else {
    DBObject update = new BasicDBObject( "$set", bo );
    collection.update( query, update );   
}
Otherwise it is not working at first time when there is no object matching the query

Comment: @IgorGrinfeld When you are not sure if the object exists and want to create it in that case, you should do this with an update with [the upsert option to true](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-parameter).